# Gradual conversion of image to greyscale with numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

Say I have an image, and I want to have it fade out to greyscale over a distance.

I already know that to entirely convert an image to greyscale with Numpy, I'd do something like

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
myImage = cv2.imread("myImage.jpg")
grey = np.dot(an_image[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
```

This is **not** what I'm looking for. I already can get that to work.

I have a `NxMx3` matrix (where `N` and `M` are the dimensions of the image), and this matrix is a dimension with the red transform, green transform, and blue transform.

So, for a given origin and radius of "keep this colored", I have

```
greyscaleWeights = np.array([0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
# We flip this so we can weight down the transformation
greyscaleWeightOffsets = np.ones(3) - greyscaleWeights
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist as getDistances
transformWeighter = list()
for rowNumber in np.arange(rowCount, dtype= 'int'):
    # Create a row of tuples containing the coordinate we are at in the picture
    row = [(x, rowNumber) for x in np.arange(columnCount, dtype= 'int')]
    # Transform this into a row of distances from our in-color center
    rowDistances = getDistances(row, [self.focusOrigin]).T[0]
    # Get the transformation weights: inside of the focus radius we have no transform, 
    # outside of the pixelDistanceToFullTransform we have a weight of 1, and an even 
    # gradation in-between
    rowWeights = [np.clip((x - self.focusRadius) / pixelDistanceToFullTransform, 0, 1) for x in rowDistances]
    transformWeighter.append(rowWeights)
# Convert this into an numpy array
transformWeighter = np.array(transformWeighter)
# Change this 1-D set of weights into 3-D weights (for each color channel)
transformRGB = np.repeat(transformWeighter[:, :, None],3, axis=1).reshape(self.image.shape)
# Change the weight offsets back into greyscale weights
greyscaleTransform = 1 - greyscaleWeightOffsets * transformRGB
greyscaleishImage = self.image * greyscaleTransform
```

I do get the fade behaviour I was hoping for, but it just fades into the green channel while nuking the red and blue, so far as I can tell.

So, for example:

[image: this test picture]

transforms into

[image: this output]

which is the correct transformation behaviour, but fading to green instead of greyscale...

Comment: As a thoroughly unrelated aside, creating the initial coordinate array is pretty slow as a loop. If someone were able to describe how to get that fully formed in Numpy, I'd appreciate it. I thought `np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: (x, y), self.image.shape[:-1], dtype= 'int')` would do it, but it doesn't behave as I expected.

Comment: _creating the initial coordinate array is pretty slow as a loop._ Which array is that, `transform_weighter` ? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I mean I'd like the array of `[[(0,0), (1, 0), (2, 0), ...], [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), ...], ...]`. Also, snake case is awful, the only thing worse is no separation wordmash haha. The java/script convention of lower-start camel-case and cap classes is clearer and less eyebleedy IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer was both easy and hard.

The premise of my question was fundamentally flawed. To quote this answer on [answers.opencv.org](https://answers.opencv.org/question/64354/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-3-channel-grayscale-from-bgr/):

> First, you must understand that a MxNx3 in greyscale doesn't exist. I mean, the concept of greyscale is that you have one channel describing the intensity on a gradual scale between black and white. So, it is not clear why would you need a 3 channels greyscale image, but if you do, I suggest that you take the value of each pixel of your 1 channel greyscale image and that you copy it three times, one on each channel of a BGR image. When a BGR image has the same value on each channel, it appears to be grey.

The correct answer then was to change the color space then desaturate the  image, so

```
imageHSV = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
newSaturationChannel = saturationWeighter * imageHSV[:,:,1]
imageHSV[:,:,1] = newSaturationChannel
greyscaleishImage = cv2.cvtColor(imageHSV, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```